# Comparing contents of text files ignoring order and format

Tags: bash, unix, compare, diff, vimdiff

I have two text files that I need to compare the contents of because one of them is missing 2 items that the other has, but I'm not sure which since they are long. I've tried `diff` and `vimdiff` with no luck. My files are both formatted like this in a jumbled order:

```
item1    item2    item3
item8    item10   item6
item32   item12   item7
```

How can I pick out which items one of text files has but the other lacks while ignoring the format and order?

Comment: you wrote **two text files**, post those input files and the expected result

Answer (score 0):

Cyrus' example is by far shorter and more to the point, but thought I'd practice some (verbose) `awk`ing ...

Sample data:

```
$ cat file1
         item2    item3
item8    item10   item6
item32   item12   item7

$ cat file2
item1    item2    item3
item8             item6
         item12   item7
```

Assumptions:

- while the description said some items could me missing from one file, I'm going to assume there could be items missing from both files
- not going to worry about sorting (for input or output)
- without guidance on **how** to display output I'll just do my own thang, to include displaying the name of the file that the item is missing from

One possible `awk` solution:

```
$ cat text.awk
BEGIN { RS="" }

NR==FNR { afile=FILENAME ; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[$i]=1 ; next }
        { bfile=FILENAME ; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) b[$i]=1        }

END {
    for (x in a)
        { if ( ! b[x] )
             { printf "missing from %s : %s\n",bfile,x }
        }
    for (x in b)
        { if ( ! a[x] )
             { printf "missing from %s : %s\n",afile,x }
        }
}
```

- `RS=""` : set row separator (`RS`) to the empty string; this turns a file into one long record
- `NR==NFR` : if this is the first (of two) files ...
- `afile=FILENAME` : save filename for later printing
- `for/a[$i]=1` : use input fields 1-NF as indexes for associative array `a`, setting array value to 1 (aka 'true')
- `next` : read next record, which in this case means read next file
- `NR!=FNR` : if this is the second (of two) files ...
- same processing except populate `bfile` and associative array `b`
- `END ...` : process our arrays ...
- `for (x in a)` : loop through the indexes of array `a` and assign to variable `x`, and if there's no comparable indexed entry in array `b` (`! b[x]`) then print a message about the array index (actually name of item from original file)  missing from `bfile`
- `for (x in b)` : same as previous loop except checking for items in `bfile` but not in `afile`

This `awk` script in action:

```
$ awk -f text.awk file1 file2
missing from file2 : item10
missing from file2 : item32
missing from file1 : item1

# switch the order of the input files => same messages, just different order
$ awk -f text.awk file2 file1
missing from file1 : item1
missing from file2 : item10
missing from file2 : item32
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use comm command.. but you should have both files in sorted order to compare:

```
comm -23 f1 f2 # will give whatever lines not matching in file1 against file2
comm -12 f1 f2 # will give matching lines
comm -13 f1 f2 # will give whatever lines not matching in file2 against file 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `comm` to compare your file in order to find what's common or distinct in them.

```
$ cat file1
item1    item2    item3
item8    item10   item6
item32   item12   item5

$ cat file2
item1    item2    item3
item8    item15   item6
item32   item12   item7
```

`comm -23 file1 file2` returns lines which are in file1 but not in file2
`comm -13 file1 file2` returns lines which are in file2 but not in file1
`comm -12 file1 file2` returns lines which common in both files

`comm` requires input files to be sorted. We'll be first converting `spaces` to `\n` via sed and then sorting via sort.

```
$ comm -23 <(sed 's/ \+/\n/g' file1 | sort ) <(sed 's/ \+/\n/g' file2 | sort)
item10
item5

$ comm -13 <(sed 's/ \+/\n/g' file1 | sort ) <(sed 's/ \+/\n/g' file2 | sort)
item15
item7

$ comm -12 <(sed 's/ \+/\n/g' file1 | sort ) <(sed 's/ \+/\n/g' file2 | sort)
item1
item12
item2
item3
item32
item6
item8
```

-- My answer ends here. ---

But just for information, man page of comm says :

```
   With no options, comm produce three-column output.  Column one contains lines unique to FILE1, column two contains lines unique to FILE2, and column three contains lines common to both files.

   -1     suppress column 1 (lines unique to FILE1)

   -2     suppress column 2 (lines unique to FILE2)

   -3     suppress column 3 (lines that appear in both files)
```

Therefore:

```
$ comm  <(sed 's/ \+/\n/g' file1 | sort ) <(sed 's/ \+/\n/g' file2 | sort)
                item1
item10
                item12
        item15
                item2
                item3
                item32
item5
                item6
        item7
                item8
```